# Setting imageDrawable to an ImageView is not shown

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having an issue in an ArrayAdapter class when setting a drawable on an imageview. At first it does not appear only if i scroll in the list.

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        loadUI(holder, convertView);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final MyObject obj = getItem(position);
    if(obj != null) {
    setAvatar(obj.getModerator(), holder);
    }

    return convertView;
}

private void setAvatar(Moderator moderator, Holder holder) {
        String avatar = moderator.getAvatar();
        if (avatar != null) {
            holder.icon.setImageUrl(avatar, ImageCacheManager.getInstance().getImageLoader());
        } else {

            TextDrawable drawable = TextDrawable.builder()
                    .beginConfig()
                    .width(60)
                    .height(60)
                    .endConfig()
                    .buildRoundRect(moderator.getAlias() != null ? moderator.getAlias() : "G", Color.BLUE, 8);

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Drawable: " + drawable);
            holder.icon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        }
    }
```

As for TextDrawable i am using this open source class: https://github.com/amulyakhare/TextDrawable/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/amulyakhare/textdrawable/TextDrawable.java

Holder class:

```
static class Holder {
        TextView authorNameTxt;
        TextView msgTxt;
        TextView timeTxt;
        com.pubble.mod.utils.CircleImageView icon;
        com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView msgPhoto;
    }
```

Basically it populates the NetworkImageView but only when i scroll and i don't understand why.

Comment: post your holder class

Comment: What is `item` in `if(item != null)`?

Comment: Sorry, i changed the names of the variables. Edited now.

Comment: "Basically it populates the NetworkImageView but..." - I don't see where you're setting an image on the NetworkImageView.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 TextDrawable drawable = mDrawableBuilder.build("G", mColorGenerator.getColor(item.data));
 holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```